# Websphere SDK rt.jar compatibility issue?

Tags: java, websphere, xalan

I'm trying to convert JSON to XML and vise versa. For that I'm using staxon jar. I'm using below code to do that.

```
Source source = new StAXSource( reader );
Result result = new StAXResult( writer );
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform( source, result );
```

If you notice in this TransformerFactory.newInstance() returns **com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl** for transform. This implementation is working fine in standalone as well as in Weblogic. But in WAS I'm getting **ClassNotFoundException** while executing this method.

I found the root cause for this, i'm using Websphere 8.5.5.0 internally it is starting with SDK1.6 in WAS installed folder. Inside SDK jre lib rt.jar **com.sun.org.apache.xalan** package is not there ??

To solve this problem i tried following ways but not achieved..

1. Trying to start WAS in normal JDK1.6 not starting giving some class notfound exception.

2. Create my own jar with all missing packages and put it into my project, on that time it is considering but XMLDocument state not START like exception I'm getting

How can I over come this problem?? Thanks

Comment: I can't tell from this, but if you aren't specifying a transformer factory to use in the code, in which case it should use the default JVM transformer factory. In IBM Java it'll be a different class (probably not Java version related), so to get a ClassNotFoundException on that class would indicate that you are overriding the default through some non-Java code basis.